# Calling a local endpoint in scala

Tags: java, scala, uri, mockups

basically I have to call a localhost mock server, at this location:

```
"127.0.0.1:8000/redfish/v1/EventService"
```

The problem is: `fromURL` wants a protocol (localhost doesn't have). `fromFile` wants a directory or a URI. Injecting a URI (created this way:

```
var uri: URI = new URI("127.0.0.1:8000/redfish/v1/EventService")
```

throws an exception:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0:
```

What method should I use to call a local endpoint?

Comment: The protocol that the local endpoint uses, probably it is an http endpoint but maybe it is an https one? Or maybe it uses something else? We really can't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a scheme:

```
val uri: URI = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:8000/redfish/v1/EventService")
```

Comment: http on localhost? ok then

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache yes, why not? It may be good to google what http means.

Comment: i perfectly know what http does... simply: can't understand why URI (technicall a local path, right?) doesnt work even without http... but ye, i did it it's ok